# Combine Facebook and Twitter Searches

Tags: php, iphone, json, facebook-graph-api, twitter

I am making search requests to both Facebook and Twitter using an iPhone application, my issue is I require to combine the searches into a single view, so to go about this I intend to make a request to an individual script on my server, which will then make the requests to both Facebook and Twitter, decode the JSON results, combine them, order by date and then output once again in JSON. This JSON will be fetched by my iPhone application, decoded and placed into a table view.

Whilst I have the client side part sorted, and am capable of making requests in PHP to obtain Facebook and Twitter search results, I have no idea how to combine them and order by date, given that the JSON keys/entities for Facebook and Twitter are different. They don't both use the same key for date, for example. How would I go about doing this?

Some code examples would be great.

Comment: Some code examples of yourself would be great too. What have you tried yourself? What is the structure of the result of a facebook or twitter search-request?

Answer (score 1):

Is there something preventing you from creating your own data object or storage method with a way to parse a Facebook or Twitter result into it?  If both results have different keys for the date as you say, you would just translate it into something you can parse.

Comment: That's my point, I am unsure how to go about combining them in such a way.